# If a photon strikes a perfectly reflecting mirror, it is essentially at rest at the instant of collision. So why does the photon exist?

Tags: special-relativity, optics, photons, speed-of-light, reflection

Photons can only move at the speed of light.how do we define its existence at the instant when it collides with a perfect mirror?

Comment: The verbal description of a photon as a pointlike particle that is abosrbed and then re-emitted has a grain of truth to it. (Technically: it's a colorful personification of the tree-level term in a small-coupling expansion of the scattering amplitude.) However, as a general practice, I would encourage you to *test* whatever alleged explanations you receive. Example: how would that description predict that the angle-of-incidence equals the angle-of-reflection? When a photon scatters from a single atom, the measured scattering angle does not obey that rule, so... why does a mirror work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The photon is never at rest. It *always* moves with the speed of light. Before the collision, it moves at the speed of light. Then it's absorbed with no intermediate state of lower velocity. After the absorption, the photon just doesn't exist anymore.

So it never is essentially at rest. Not even at the time of absorption. One moment it has a speed c, the next moment it's not there, not being able to have zero velocity.

So *at the moment* of its absorption, there is no change of velocity because the next moment there is no photon anymore to have a zero velocity. Only upon reemission, it will acquire (instantaneously) a velocity in the reflected direction. The same argument holds for the reemission.

Comment: This answer correctly describes what happens when a photon is absorbed by a particle, but it does not directly answer this question. The full picture is that the photon is absorbed by a particle on the surface and then reemitted. Another important clarification is that the speed of light is different in the material than in vacuum, but conceptually I agree with this answer!

Comment: @QuantumEngineer Yes, you are right. I'll edit.

Comment: @QuantumEngineer Ah yes. Do you mean that the light can be decelerated?

Comment: I mean that the light travels at a reduced velocity in a medium, given by $c/n$ where $c$ is the speed of light and $n$ is the refractive index of the medium. For glass, $n=1.5$ so the speed of light will be only $2/3$ the speed of light in vacuum.

Comment: @QuantumEngineer Doesn't a photon *always* travel at the speed of light?

Comment: No, the speed of light in vacuum is always constant (no matter what reference frame or whether you are on earth or in space etc.), but the speed of light in a medium (air, water, glass, etc.) is less than the speed of light in vacuum. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index.

Comment: I asked about a perfect mirror. No absorption or transmission

Comment: @AbdurRahim The photon doesn't bounce like a massive ball, which indeed must have an intermediate velocity of zero. When reflected, the photon is absorbed and re-emitted in opposite direction.

Comment: @QuantumEngineer Although I find everything about this hard to grasp, I am rather sure that the photons are *not* re-emitted in the original direction. This would imply that the reflection goes in the same direction as the incoming light and that we would see ourselves in a mirror from every angle. I understand that "in the mirror" the photons are emitted randomly (regarding angular directions), which overall leads to constructive and destructive interference and to the reflection angle of the incoming wave on macroscopic scale as we know it (Huygens–Fresnel principle).

Comment: @AbdurRahim A mirror has to absorb and re-emit the photons on microscopic scale, without it it would not be a mirror, but transparent.

Comment: @Koschi You are correct - what I was saying was just a simplified picture to give a feeling for what was going on, but since it was probably misleading, I deleted the comment. By original direction, I was just considering the case where the light was incident perpendicular to the mirror.